# How to make a Cross-thread Operation using a form textBox thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

In c# (Visual-Studio-Express 2013), the following code creates the error described below:

```
public void AddToAppLog(string formatter, string loggerId, string logText)
{
  lock(this)
  {
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    string logEntry =   dateTime.Hour.ToString("00")
                      + ":"
                      + dateTime.Minute.ToString("00")
                      + ":"
                      + dateTime.Second.ToString("00")
                      + "."
                      + dateTime.Millisecond.ToString("000")
                      + " [" + loggerId.PadRight(18, '·') + "]" + "> " 
                      + formatter
                      + logText
                      + "\n";
    applicationLog.AppendText(logEntry);
  } // end of lock
} // end of member function:  AddToAppLog
```

Error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'applicationLog' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

What do I need to do ?

Comment: There's an OK write-up about multi-threading and Windows Forms controls here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms171728%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  It may be that you can simplify things by using a BackgroundWorker and altering your controls in ProgressChanged or RunWorkerCompleted handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
applicationLog.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        applicationLog.AppendText(logEntry);
    });
```

Comment: @skuenstler: Need more help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to set a property of an object that is owned by the UI thread from a worker thread, which causes the cross-thread exception.

To properly communicate between your worker thread and the UI thread, a common pattern is to use the `Control.Invoke` mechanism. You need a function like this:

```
private void AppendToAppLog(string text)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (applicationLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(s => applicationLog.AppendText(s)), text);
    }
    else
    {
        applicationLog.AppendText(text);
    }
}
```

And then you can call this function instead of the `AppendText` method in your sample code.

```
AppendToAppLog(logEntry);
```

This code ensures that you can append text from both the UI thread and the worker threads, and it will not use Control.Invoke if not needed (e.g. when calling this method from the UI thread).

Here is an example of invoking your method from worker threads and the UI thread at the same time:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => AddToAppLog("", "5215", "Append first"), null);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddToAppLog("", "5215", "Append second"));

    AddToAppLog("", "5215", "Append third");
}
```

And the resulting textbox value:

```
14:26:40.533 [5215··············]> Append third
14:26:40.534 [5215··············]> Append first
14:26:40.554 [5215··············]> Append second
```